# Simple high school inequality question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm reviewing some high school basic algebra and I would like to know when this function:

> $$2x-1-\frac{1}{x}$$

is positive.

**Solution**

Suppose $x\gt0$, then $2x-1-\frac{1}{x}\ge0\Leftrightarrow 2x^2-x-1\ge 0\Leftrightarrow x\ge 1$.

Suppose $x\lt 0$, then $2x-1-\frac{1}{x}\ge0\Leftrightarrow 2x^2-x-1\le 0\Leftrightarrow -1/2\le x\lt 0$

Then $2x-1-\frac{1}{x}\ge 0 \Leftrightarrow  x\ge 1$ and $-1/2\le x\lt 0$.

Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: Since $x\neq0$, you can also try multiplying with $x^2$ instead of x

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis good remark, this simplify everything, can you post this as an answer so that I can upvote it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $x\neq0$, instead if taking 2 cases for $x\gt0$ and $x\lt0$, you know that your function $f(x)$ has the same sign with $x^2f(x)$.

$x^2f(x)=x^2(2x-1-\frac{1}{x})=2x^3-x^2-x=2x(x-1)(x+\frac12)$

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is **nearly** right.

It should be $-1/2<x<0$  **or**  $x>1$. Think about it. How can $x$ satisfy *both* of these inequalities at the same time?

Also note the strict inequalities: it should be $<$ rather than $\leq,$ and $>$ rather than $\geq$.

Comment: yes, you're right thanks for point me these out.

Comment: How do you solve this inequality without the assumptions $x\gt 0$ and $x\lt 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$2x-1-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{2x^2-x-1}{x}=\frac{(x-1 )(x+\frac{1}{2})}{x}$

Comment: Why so large beginning?